# Using "servir à qn à qch"

Tags: expressions, verbes

The expression [servir à qn](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/servir-%C3%A0-qn) means "to be of use to somebody", and [servir à qch/à faire qch](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/servir-%C3%A0-qch-%C3%A0-faire) means "to be used for something/for doing something." Can I use both simultaneously?

> Ce livre **me** sert beaucoup **à** réviser pour l'examen.
>
> Ce livre sert beaucoup **à** Alain **à** réviser pour l'examen.

or should I change the second **à** to **pour**?

> Ce livre **me** sert beaucoup **pour** réviser pour l'examen.
>
> Ce livre sert beaucoup **à** Alain **pour** réviser pour l'examen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use *pour réviser* in both cases, but remove the last *pour* and optionally replace it that way:

> *Ce livre me sert beaucoup pour réviser mon examen*.
>
> *Ce livre sert beaucoup à Alain pour réviser son examen*.

There can be a slight nuance between both expressions:

*Me servir à* = is appropriate for me to do something.

*Me servir pour* = is used by me to do something.

Comment: Is it common to say "réviser mon examen" without a preposition? Normally I would imagine we can revise a book, revise our biology, but revise *for* an exam.

Comment: It is much more common to say *révise ton bac !* or *révise le bac !* than *révise pour le bac !*.